# How can you create a knowledgebase in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Trying to create a knowledgebase for our small team and was after some advice on the best way to do it using sharepoint foundation 2013. Anybody know of any free apps which may do the job?

Any help/advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score -1):

In Sharepoint the best and the simple way is to use the SPList.

But you cannot create a link between different lists.

roironm